# Error call to a member function bindParam() on boolean php al usar el driver mysqli (INSERTING DATA)

Tags: php, pdo

*El error es tal que este:*

```
[25-Jun-2019 03:14:24 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in /ruta/ipn.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /ruta/ipn.php on line 79
```

La linea es esta `$sentencia->bindParam(':id_ass', $id);`
y el código este:

```
        $sentencia = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices (id_ass, invoiceid, packageid, paypalemail) VALUES (:id_ass, :invoiceid, :packageid, :paypalemail)");
        $sentencia->bindParam(':id_ass', $id);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':invoiceid', $_POST['txn_id']);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':packageid', $packageid);
        $sentencia->bindParam(':paypalemail', $_POST['payer_email']);
        $sentencia->execute();
```

Este error tengo entendido que suele pasar cuando faltan valores, el problema es que no encuentro los valores que faltan. Soy nuevo en esto de usar consultas preparadas en el nuevo driver de mysqli entonces pues aún no me entero mucho.
Saludos.

**Foto de la base de datos:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si es mysqli el que usas entonces no se escribe así, se escribe `bind_param()`

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() mismo error :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás confundiendo sintaxis, mencionas en el título de tu pregunta usar *mysqli* pero la sintaxis que muestras es PDO, por eso el fallo.

Tu código debería ser así:

```
$sentencia = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices (id_ass, invoiceid, packageid, paypalemail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sentencia->bind_param('iiis', $id, $_POST['txn_id'], $packageid, $_POST['payer_email']);
$sentencia->execute();
```

- En MySQLI las sentencias preparadas usan marcadores de posición con el símbolo de: `?`
- El método en MySQLI se llama `bind_param` y se pasan primero entre comillas el tipo de dato que recibe, que puede ser:

  - `i` integer
  - `s` string
- Posterior pasas separados por comas las variables que van a procesarse para la consulta

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Como digo soy nuevo en este driver jaja.

Comment: ahora funciona perfecto.

Comment: El código da errores pero los datos no se llegan a almacenar en la base de dats

Comment: que error te da? @MarkosTech

Comment: perdón, queria decir no da errores

Comment: El log del ipn de paypal se llega a ejecutar demostrando que el código se ejecuta entero

Comment: He añadido una foto de la bd arriba @Aprendiz

Comment: después del execute añade este código y dime si retorna algún mensaje `if(!$sentencia){
  echo $conn->errno ." ". $conn->error;
}` @MarkosTech

Comment: No retorna nada

Comment: Además si hubiera algún error el código no se ejecutaria, ya que en la database.php está especificado que si hay error haga exit;

Comment: Mmm, si lo ejecuto fuera seteando yo las variables si va. Puede que las variables no sean del tipo que tienen que ser ¿?

Comment: correcto, faltaba una variable por declarar :/. Muchas gracias por ayudarme ;).

Comment: recién leo tu mensaje, cual variable faltaba por declarar @MarkosTech? el alta si procede si se almacenan los datos en tu tabla?

Comment: Si, ahora se almacenan. $packageid no estaba declarada.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de cambiar tu *Prepared Statement* a esta forma:

```
 $sentencia = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices (id_ass, invoiceid, packageid, paypalemail) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
 $sentencia->bind_param('ssss', $id, $_POST['txn_id'], $packageid, $_POST['payer_email']);
 $sentencia->excute();
```

Suponiendo que todas tus variables son `string`, ponemos en el `bind_param('ssss'...)` De no ser así deberíamos cambiar por el tipo de dato que sea tu variable. Por ejemplo tu variable `$packegeid` no es un `string` sino un `numero entero`, entonces quedaría así  `bind_param('ssis'...)`

Comment: Perfecto gracias :).

Comment: Amigo, se te ha olvidado cambiar stmt a sentencia. Pero igualmente el código no se ejecuta, lo estamos discutiendo en la pregunta de arriba